# SignalR callback not firing when hosting in IIS

Tags: iis-7.5, signalr

I'm using the Chat demo for SignalR 2.0 and MVC5 [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5).  I added an NServiceBus backplane and everything works fine in IISExpress.

However, when I host in IIS 7.5 on Windows 7, my client callbacks are not firing.  I turned client logging on and this is the log:

```
[14:13:42 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'chathub'. jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js:8
[14:13:42 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D&clientProtocol=1.3'. jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js:8

[14:13:42 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://localhost:8020/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connection…z5pLeBNULTyEhm&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D&tid=2'. jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js:8

[14:13:42 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource connected. jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js:8

[14:13:47 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents timed out when trying to connect. jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js:8

[14:13:47 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close(). jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js:8

[14:13:47 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: This browser supports SSE, skipping Forever Frame. jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js:8

[14:13:47 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http://localhost:8020/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken…z5pLeBNULTyEhm&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D&tid=5'. jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js:8

[14:13:52 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: longPolling timed out when trying to connect. jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js:8

[14:13:52 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: Aborted xhr request. jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js:8

maybe the server is down chat:91

[14:13:52 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: Stopping connection. jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js:8

[14:13:52 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)] SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = true.
```

The AppPool is configured for .NET 4.0 and I have this in the web.config:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a full version of IIS on a client OS is not recommended. See "Supported server IIS versions" here:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/supported-platforms

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the problem is caused by using SignalR in combination with nservicebus and IIS I have different working solutions with this. The IIS settings that you mention are the same for my solutions. I also run IIS on Windows 7 Maybe you can find something different in the web.config Here is mine :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>   
<section name="DBSubscriptionStorageConfig"                  type="NServiceBus.Config.DBSubscriptionStorageConfig, NServiceBus.NHibernate" />
<section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
</configSections>
<UnicastBusConfig ForwardReceivedMessagesTo=.audit">
<MessageEndpointMappings>
  <add Messages="Transport.Events" Endpoint=.Transport.Service" />
</MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
<DBSubscriptionStorageConfig UpdateSchema="true">
<NHibernateProperties>
  <add Key="connection.provider" Value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"   />       
  <add Key="connection.driver_class" Value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver" />
  <add Key="connection.connection_string" Value="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial catalog=NServiceBus;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
  <add Key="dialect" Value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect" />
</NHibernateProperties>
</DBSubscriptionStorageConfig>
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
 <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
 <handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
<runtime>
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="StructureMap" publicKeyToken="e60ad81abae3c223" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.4.0" newVersion="2.6.4.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>  
</configuration>
```